# Equation of the plane tangent to the given area

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces

Find the equation of the plane tangent to the surface:
$$x^{\frac{1}{3}}+y^{\frac{1}{3}}+z^{\frac{1}{3}}=1$$ at the point:
$$P=\left(1,-1,1\right)$$
How to find it? I know i have to calculate a gradient which is:
$$\left(\frac{1}{3}x^{-\frac{2}{3}}, \frac{1}{3}y^{-\frac{2}{3}}, \frac{1}{3}z^{-\frac{2}{3}} \right)$$ but what should i do next? I think i need to substitute point into the gradient but how to substitute this point if i have $-1$ under the root?

Comment: Is n't it a surface?

Comment: possibly, but still this does not interfere with the matter of the question as such

Comment: you can work out the gradient vector using your values of $x, y, z$, then get the equation of the plane using $r\cdot n=a\cdot n$

Comment: could you elaborate on that further? I do not understand fully what you mean by that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of a plane can be written as

$$\vec N\cdot (\vec r-\vec r_0)=0 \tag 1$$

where $\vec r$ spans the plane, $\vec r_0$ is any specified point on the plane, and $\vec N$ is a vector that is normal to the plane.

Here, we have a surface defined by the equation

$$f(x,y,z)=x^{1/3}+y^{1/3}+z^{1/3}-1=0$$

We know that the gradient of $f$, evaluated on the surface, is a vector that is normal to the surface.  The gradient of $f$ is

$$\nabla f(x,y,z)=\frac13(\hat xx^{-2/3}+\hat yy^{-2/3}+ \hat zz^{-2/3})$$

At the point $(1,-1,1)$, the gradient of $f$ is $\nabla f(1,-1,1)=\frac13(\hat x+\hat y + \hat z)$ and points normal to the surface defined by $f=0$.  Thus,

$$\vec N=\hat x+\hat y + \hat z \tag 2$$

is vector normal to the surface $f=0$ at the point

$$\vec r_0=\hat x-\hat y + \hat z \tag 3$$

Using $(2)$ and $(3)$ in $(1)$ gives the equation of the plane normal to the surface $f=0$ at the point $(1,-1,1)$ as

$$(x-1)+(y+1)+(z-1)=0\implies x+y+z=1$$